# django filefield saving behavior

Tags: django

I have a class like this

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    def save_path(instance, filename):
        return os.path.join('/foobar/%s' % instance.name, '%s' % filename

    name = models.CharField()
    bar = models.FileField(upload_to=save_path)
```

I have this working like I want it to, but my problem is that if there is already a file with the same name uploaded, it creates a duplicate and appends a random unique string on the name. I would rather like to just ignore the new file and keep the old one in this case since in my situation they will be the same file anyway

Comment: If its really going to be the same file do you really need it to be a `FileField` or would a [`FilePathField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#filepathfield) work?

Comment: I originally wanted to use FilePathField, but I couldn't get it to work with relative URL's (like with FileField and MEDIA_ROOT, and url()) and I was advised to just use FileField.

Comment: Well one of the problems with what your trying to do with overwriting is that if any other instance of the model is still using the previous file then you will have 'broken' that model... What is the file for?

Comment: its an audio clip for a word that may be used in multiple models

Comment: That sounds more like a static asset...

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you would do then? I am drawing a blank

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do with it, make your audio clip a static asset and then reference that in the pages you need to (do you need to store it in the db?), you can even save the name of the asset in your model if you want and then just reference it that way

Comment: hmmmm. You mean use a CharField to store the location of the static files? and then reference that? That may work I will have to try it. How would I go about storing it in the db if I needed to? BinaryField?

Comment: A FileField would work for that. and yeah essentially a `CharField`, I'm not sure if there is another field available. I've never really tried using the static tag with a variable but should be fine

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use the static tag in the pages because I am doing some asynchronous (I think thats the proper term) requests and the template will have already rendered the tags. I think I just realized I ay not even need the db at all, I'll play with it and see what I can come up with